# Using Python's pickle in Sage results in high memory usage

Tags: python, memory-management, sage

I am using the Python based Sage Mathematics software to create a very long list of vectors. The list contains roughly 100,000,000 elements and sys.getsizeof() tells me that it is of size a little less than 1GB.

This list I pickle into a file (which already takes a long time -- but fair enough). Only when I unpickle this list it gets annoying. The RAM usage increases from 1.15GB to 4.3GB, and I am wondering what's going on?

How can I find out in Sage what all the memory is used for? And do you have any ideas how to optimize this by maybe applying Python tricks?

---

This is a reply to the comment of kcrisman.

The exact code I cannot post since it would be too long. But here is a simple example where the phenomena can be observed. I am working on Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Start Sage and execute:

```
import pickle
L = [vector([1,2,3]) for k in range(1000000)]
f = open("mylist", 'w')
pickle.dump(L, f)
```

On my system the list is 8697472 bytes big, and the file I pickled into has roughly 130MB. Now close Sage and watch your memory (with htop, for example). Then execute the following lines:

```
import pickle
f = open("mylist", 'r')
pickle.load(f)
```

Without sage my Linux system uses 1035MB of memory, when Sage is running the usage increases to 1131MB. After I unpickled the file it uses 2535MB which I find odd.

Comment: If you're using one of the more custom algebraic objects, there may be a memory leak... can you post the exact code, though?  It's possible there is some inefficiency which is causing some duplication of memory needed.

Comment: I strongly recommend using hdf5 files instead (e.g. using the h5py module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably better to not use python's pickle module directly. cPickle is already a bit better, but a lot of pickling in sage assumes protocol 2, which (c)Pickle doesn't default to. You can use sage's own wrappers of pickle. If I do your example with

```
sage: open("mylist",'w').write(dumps(L))
```

and then load it in a fresh session via

```
sage: L = loads(open("mylist",'r').read())
```

I observe no problems.

Note that the above interface is not the best one to pickle/unpickle in sage to a file. You'd be better off using `save/load`. I just did it that way to stay as close as possible to your example.